# reference - event object attributes

Tags: javascript

Regarding the code below, how does the interpreter know that event has attribute .keyCode.  This code works, I just don't understand completely why, and more so were is this documented.  How does it know what type of object event is.  What if I would have called it 'e' or 'e1'.  Where is the method prototype f1(Event) documented?

```
function b0(event) 
  {if (event.keyCode==13) 
    {i4(); 
    return false;}} 


function o5('f4b_',b0); 

o5(a,b){document.getElementById(a).onkeypress=b;}
```

where the element id a is an input text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of event is irrelevant, inside the function it's just another variable. You can rename it to JellyMan, and if you rename `if (event.keyCode==13)` to `if (JellyMan.keyCode==13)` it will work fine.

The type of event is determined by the script at run-time. The interpreter does not know that event has an attribute of .keyCode - if you tried to call it, and passed in a parameter that isn't the correct type: `b0('wheee, break it');` then it will fail.

When the author wrote the script, he decided that function b0 would take one parameter (he called it event) and it would be a eventHandler - this doesn't get specified anywhere, it's just assumed that nobody's going to call it with something else. All eventHandlers have a .keyCode attribute, so it's therefore assumed that the object being passed in has one.

Comment: k, but how does the event object make it to the function?  I attach the function to an input text box onkeypress event..there must be some documentation somewhere which sais all functions attached to a textbox onkeypress event will fit this prototype f1(event)...where is this stated?

Comment: You're wrong that "all eventHandlers have a .keyCode attribute". Firstly, they are event **objects**, secondly they have **properties**, not attributes. Lastly, only key events should be expected to have a (non-standard) *.keyCode* property, the basic [event interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-Event) doesn't have one. There is a DOM 3 [keyboard event interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-KeyboardEvent) but it's only a working draft. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/KeyEvent) is probably a better resource.

Comment: When you define a custom event handler, like this, you're basically overwriting the default event handler. That's a function buried away god-knows-where inside Javascript itself, and the first parameter for that function is an eventHandler (because that is what was decided when JS was written). As such, when we override the default handler, JS will give us an eventHandler as the first parameter of the new method. We might not do anything with it; `function b0 () { do stuff }` but it's there if we want to.

Comment: @chris - how the event object gets to the function depends on the browser and how the listener is attached. Here's an [article on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html) that might help, it's not perfect but it's ok for starters.

Comment: @RobG: I'm trying to make it easy to understand, not 100% accurate down to all the details :P Life is just learning something, finding out something else that reveals the first thing was just an easy-to-understand lie, then finding out something else that reveals that was another easy-to-understand lie, and so on :P

Comment: thanks for the documentation (mdn)...it appears I should be using .key instead of .keyCode as it is deprecated...

Comment: so the run-time system passes my method this object...but there must be documentation somewhere that has a reference like method(Event) similar to how php.net has their functions documented.  I did not see this method prototype in any of the listed web sites.

Comment: @Joe - sorry, busy at work, no down vote. :-) It really matters to get terminology correct because people pick it up casually and the re-use it inappropriately. Calling javacript object properties "attributes" matters in particular becaue many don't realise the clear distinction between javascript properties and HTML attributes and confusion reigns as a result (e.g. jQuery's *attr* function confused the two for years, now they've finally cleaned it up, but not before creating a big headache).

Comment: Very fair point :) I'll make sure I remember that. I'm pretty sure I've read it somewhere before, and just not registered it as important heh, but yes, I can see where the confusion comes in. And JS has more than its fair share of confusion.

Comment: mdn lists them as attributes....anyways.....key does not work...i changed it back to .keyCode even thought it is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter doesn't have to "know".  When the runtime system invokes an event handler, it passes it an object with more-or-less well-documented properties.

If you ran that code in a broken browser that passed in weird event objects, the code would fail.

Comment: so the run-time system passes my method this object...but there must be documentation somewhere that has a reference like method(Event) similar to how php.net has their functions documented.  I did not see this method prototype in any of the listed web sites.

Comment: Not the function so much, but the event object itself is documented.  JavaScript does not have strict function signatures.  You can call **any** function with any set of parameters you want. It may not work, but the function call itself will be carried out with no complaints from the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that javascript is interpreted code, not pre-compiled code.  Any variable can hold any type.

So, in the function `b0`, the 2nd line of code:

```
if (event.keyCode==13)
```

says to the interpreter to get the first parameter passed to the function (named `event`) and fetch the attribute from it named `keyCode`.  Javascript will look at the event parameter and see if it is the right type of variable to have an attribute and whether it actually has an attribute named `keyCode`.  If it does, it will fetch it's value and compare it to 13.  If it is not the right type of variable to have any attributes, then that line of code will fail and javascript will throw an exception.  If it is the right type of variable to have an attribute, but does not have an attribute named `keyCode` then it will proceed with a value for that attribute of `undefined` which will fail the equality test with 13.

Comment: k, but how does the event object make it to the function?  I attach the function to an input text box onkeypress event..there must be some documentation somewhere which sais all functions attached to a textbox onkeypress event will fit this prototype f1(event)...where is this stated.

Comment: When the browser calls the function assigned to onkeypress, it calls that function with the first parameter as the event object with a set of specified attributes on that object.  The system creates that event object when the event happens.   It's part of a specification that the onkeyup event handler should have this as it's first parameter.